# Debut shopify theme: Change image size on Collection page

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout, shopify-template

I am working in Debut shopify theme. 
I want to make the 4 images that are in a row larger.

My current page:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYa7W.png)

My goal: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdfpa.jpg)

I found a similiar question here:

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/solo-theme-change-product-image-size-on-collection-page-342056#comment-342234

but they are refering to another theme.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a code or shop url?

Comment: https://dzoni-bomboni.myshopify.com/collections/dresses

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Theme>sections>collection-list.liquid

Find this line of code:

```
{% when '4' %}
  {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-whole medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
  {%- assign image_size = '250x250' -%}
```

Change the 250x250 to your desired size.

Also in the debut theme there is a default page width so it may interfere with the look it seems you are going for unless you change that.