# How can i add this customization to my Shopify debut theme?

Tags: themes, shopify

I'm trying to do some customization to my Debut theme in Shopify. On the home page I'm trying to customize my Featured images sizes. Shopify gives you the ability to adjust how many pictures you can put on a row and the sizes adjust accordingly.

**Problem 1:**  I want to have 4 pictures per row but use the same sizing as 3 pictures on a row.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585749/debut-shopify-theme-change-image-size-on-collection-page) on the forum and it helped with the sizing.

These photos are the areas where I made the adjustments (may not show sizing adjustments in pictures). It did make the photos larger when done.

[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

[image]

**Problem 2:**  This increased the picture size, but it puts the 4th picture on a separate row. I"m pretty sure this has to do with the page sizing. I'm struggling to find the page / box width to adjust sizing to keep all the pictures in the same row.

[image]

[image]

I tried to adjust the div width, but it didn't work.

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, I would assume the width is controlled by the `.page_width` selector in your theme.scss.liquid file